# редактировать элементы массива angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

в `$scope.reviews = {};` помещаю массив. 
Где мне нужно я вызываю что-нибудь в духе:

```
<div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
    {{review.id}} {{review.name}} {{review.date}}
</div>
```

Как мне сделать определенную операцию с определенным *столбцом* этого массива? Например форматировать дату. Я хочу это делать не на стороне шаблона, а в контроллере.

Comment: что значит _в $scope.reviews = {}; помещаю массив_? _Как мне сделать определенную операцию с определенным столбцом этого массива ... не на стороне шаблона, а в контроллере_ - нужно пройтись циклом по **массиву** и поменять что нужно

Comment: При успешном вызове `$http` делаю `$scope.reviews = result.data.reviews;`. Как обойти массив в ангуляре? Заметил, что многие штуки тут отличаются от классического яваскрипта. Ощущение, что делаю что-то не то. Если бы это был не массив, а один элемент то обращаться я бы мог через `$scope.reviews.id` или т.д.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `angular.forEach($scope.reviews,function(review){})`.

Comment: в данном случае, если ты получаешь действительно массив - это обычный массив и обходить его надо как обычно: for, forEach и т.д.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko `        angular.forEach($scope.reviews.updated_at, function(review) {
                $scope.reviews.updated_at = $scope.reviews.updated_at.split(" ",3);
        });` не работает. На вход подаю строку в формате `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko мой цикл вообще не отрабатывается. что-то делаю не так.

Comment: Потому что не зря я в комментарии написал `$scope.reviews`. `angular.forEach` работает с массивом. Вам надо сделать так: `angular.forEach($scope.reviews, function(review) { review.updated_at = review.updated_at.split(" ",3); });`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko работает, спасибо

Comment: Лучше посмотрите на ответ @Qwertiy. Надеюсь, он вам приведет пример, как использовать фильтр в шаблоне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var format = $filter("date");

for (var q=0; q<$scope.reviews.length; ++q) {
  $scope.reviews[q].date = format($scope.reviews[q].date, "yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Но вообще, логичнее использовать фильтры из разметки. Начиная с версии 1.3 ангуляр по умолчанию не выполняет повторных вызовов фильтров.

```
<div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
    {{review.date | date : "yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss"}}
</div>
```

Comment: Я благодарен за проявленное внимание, но ответ не соответствует вопросу.

Comment: @J.Doe, сорри, невнимательно прочитал. Ответ обновлён.

Comment: Да, для вывода форматированных значений лучше использовать фильтры в шаблоне. Может, добавите пример использования фильтра в шаблоне? Надо же показывать, как лучше сделать, а не поощрять человека, когда он движется в неверном направлении))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, готово.

Comment: Пришел к такому не стандартному варианту именно потому, что `| date : "yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss"` не работает, не смотря на то что `$filter` к контроллеру подключен и вообще в консоли все хорошо

Comment: @J.Doe, всё работает, если только ты фильтру не какой-то мусор скармливаешь. Покажи неработающий пример.

Comment: Похоже, у спрашивающего в свойстве `review.updated_at` не тип `Date`, а `String`. Поэтому фильтр `date` и не работает. Это видно из его преобразования `review.updated_at = review.updated_at.split(" ",3);`. Может, покажете, как создать и использовать кастомный фильтр.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, вроде date-фильтр умеет строки парсить, если формат съедобный. А кастомный фильтр - это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Согласен, необходимо создать новый вопрос - как распарсить дату с произвольным форматом, с помощью кастомного фильтра)